# Grease Pencil rendering and view port

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, grease-pencil

When I use Grease Pencil I get this weird antialiasing or overlapping issue - the line is drawn on the surface with an offset - it's not going into the cube - furthermore I have Z passes enabled -

I've using a macbook pro m1 2021

Thanks for your help

[image: greasepencil]